# how to create a search bar with an image submit button inside of it

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a search bar exactly like Google Images'.

This is my html code so far:

```
        <form id="search"; action="https://www.google.com/images">
        <input type="text" name="q">
        </form>
```

And my css:

```
input[type="text"]{
border-radius:50px;
-moz-border-radius:50px;
-webkit-border-radius:50px;
width: 600px;
height: 25px; 
padding: 12px 20px;
border-color: lightgrey;
background-color: white;
background-image: url('searchicon.png');
background-position: 10px 10px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 25px;
padding-left: 50px;
outline: none;
}
```

So far, the image is inside the search bar but it doesn't do anything. I'd like for it to redirect me to a link, please.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot insert a button inside an input (which is a text box in your case). What I have done is placed a button on top of the text box.

CSS and HTML changes are the following:

```css
.search {
display: inline-block;
box-sizing: border-box;
line-height: 20px;    
border-radius:50px;
-moz-border-radius:50px;
-webkit-border-radius:50px;
box-sizing: border-box;
line-height: 20px;
height: 30px; 
vertical-align:middle;
padding: 12px 20px;
}

.textbox {
 border-color: lightgrey;
 width: 600px;
}

.submit-button {
background-image: url("https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/hawcons/32/698627-icon-111-search-256.png");
line-height: inherit;
text-decoration: none;
cursor: pointer;
width: 35px;
background-position: 5px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 20px;
background-color: transparent;
margin-left:-45px;
border:none;
}
```

```html
<form id="search" method="get" action="https://www.google.com/images">
   <input class="search textbox" type="text" name="q">
   <input class="search submit-button" type="button" type="submit" value="">
</form>
```

You will have to change the icon and do the necessary style changes.

Comment: Well, did you remove the semicolon in the form element? When you type any text and hit enter you should be redirected to google images site

Comment: If i do it that way it does work, but I want to be able to click the image and be redirected to the page

Comment: Check the answer :-)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, it has helped me a lot. And also sorry for the late answer, I suddenly got quite busy these days... Really appreciate it.